# How can I modify User Preferences in Sublime Text 2 via a Build System?

Tags: html, editor, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

#### What I want

- How can I 'build' an HTML file so that it opens in my browser and Sublime Text 2 does not display a build panel?
- More generally, how can I interact with Sublime Text 2 settings from my `.sublime-build` files?

I'm on Mac OS X/Chrome 32.0.1700.102.

I'd like to suppress the build panel in Sublime Text 2 (ST2) on a per-build-system basis.  If necessary, I'd be OK suppressing depending on the syntax of the open window.  Basically, I want to be able to open an HTML file I'm editing in my browser without seeing the `[Finished in 0.01s]` output at the bottom of the screen.  An analogous question has been asked [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/514893/sublime-settings-syntax-specific-show-panel-on-build-not-overriding-with-ma).

The setting to change is `show_panel_on_build` and my `HTML.sublime-build` is simply
    {
        "cmd": ["open", "$file"]
    }

#### What I've tried

When I add `"show_panel_on_build": false` to `HTML.sublime-build` my builds hang and do not complete (and the panel shows up!).

I also tried installing [Better Build System](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Better%20Build%20System), but then my build stopped working entirely.  I did not investigate the issue in detail.

Obviously, I could so something silly like write a script which modifies my User Preferences file outside of ST2, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any thoughts (or pointers to appropriate plugins) appreciated.  Thanks!